# Некорректное выполнение условий функции

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть объект, к которому применяется определенный класс в зависимости от значения атрибута "data". Задача в том, чтобы реализовать возможность изменения класса при клике на него. Все срабатывает только один раз, при повторном нажатии на объект ничего не происходит, хотя функция favoritecheck значение переменной получает.

```
<div id="favorite" data="1"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var favorite = $("#favorite").attr("data");  // Присвоение переменной значения из data
    favoritecheck (favorite);  // Направление переменной в функцию favoritecheck

function favoritecheck () {
    if (favorite == 0) {          // Функция добавляет класс объекту исходя из значения переменной
        $("#favorite").addClass("favorite0");}
    else {
        $("#favorite").addClass("favorite1");};
    //alert(favorite);
};

$("#favorite").click(function (){
    if (favorite == 0) {favorite = 1} // Изменение значения переменной при клике на объект
    else {favorite = 0};
favoritecheck (favorite);  // Направление переменной в функцию favoritecheck 
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Что получает ф-я `favoritecheck`??? Ничего она не получает, вы на сигнатуру ее посмотрите. Используемый в ней `favorite` - это замыкание внешней переменной.

Т.е. вам надо сделать как-то так:

    function favoritecheck (favorite)
    ....

Хотя в этих ваших `favorite` запутаться можно. Я бы в функции назвал ее не `favorite`, а как-то `newFavorite`

Comment: @VANIAN, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, это всё стоит упростить одной функцией при клике.

```
$("#favorite").click(function(){
    f = $("#favorite").attr("data");
    if(f==="0") {
        $(this).attr("data", "1");
        $(this).addClass("favorite0");
    } else {
        $(this).attr("data", "0");
        $(this).addClass("favorite1");
    }
});
```

А еще посмотрите [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/), возможно, он Вам лучше подойдет, если изначально допускается присваивание класса, это всё можно просто записать в одну строку:

HTML:

```
<div id="favorite" class="favorite0"></div>
```

JS:

```
$("#favorite").click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass("favorite0").toggleClass("favorite1")
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но нужно, чтобы скрипт присваивал объекту определенный класс на основе значения атрибута data (полученного из базы данных) еще до клика, а после клика изменял. При этом нужно не просто добавить класс, а изменить переменную, чтобы отправить обновленное значение на сервер. Вот пример http://jsfiddle.net/g865t8kv/5/. Может как-то можно упростить?